# SSH, RabbitMQ, Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: econnrefused

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

When I try to run on my server machine command

```
./rabbitmq-server
```

I the get following:

```
WARNING: Removing trailing slash from RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE
         Removing trailing slash from RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE
Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: econnrefused
```

Backstory:
This is my first time I'm trying to install RabbitMQ-Server **just using ssh**.

Step-by-step what I did so far would be:

1. wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.0/rabbitmq-server-3.6.15.zip
2. unzip rabbitmq-server-3.6.15.zip
3. nano Makefile # change prefix to rabbitMQ in home directory PREFIX ?= /home/user/rabbitmq
4. gmake
5. gmake install
6. cd ~/rabbitmq/lib/erlang/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.15/sbin/
7. export RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE=/home/user/rabbitmq/lib/erlang/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.15/sbin/ 
   export RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/home/user/rabbitmq/
8. ./rabbitmq-server

And here comes the error. I was told that maybe "unlocking" ports would do the trick, but

- I don't know how to do that
- I don't know if that's the case

Comment: Why are you not using the latest pre-packaged release for your operating system? If that is not an option, use the [`generic-unix`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v3.7.7/rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-3.7.7.tar.xz) package. Compiling RabbitMQ yourself should not be necessary and will only cause headaches like you're seeing. Finally, what Erlang version are you using?

Comment: From what Legoscia posted below, it seems like it's not RabbitMQ's failure, but rather epmd.

My version is 19

Comment: @LukeBakken IME, compiling Erlang apps/projects is totally fine (and seemingly common). Is RabbitMQ particularly hard to compile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error `Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: econnrefused` means that the Erlang node tried to connect to epmd (the Erlang port mapper daemon) to register its name, but failed to connect.

That shouldn't happen: epmd should be started when the Erlang node starts up.  You could try running `epmd` manually in the shell, and see if it reports any errors.

---

If it says `failed to bind socket: Operation not permitted`, check if something else is using port 4369 (which is the port that epmd tries to listen on).

Comment: Hello,
Running epmd gives me error
[user@xxx]:<~>$ epmd
epmd: Wed Aug  1 11:51:19 2018: failed to bind socket: Operation not permitted

Comment: Right, that would be the source of the problem. Not sure why it wouldn't have permission to listen on the port. It's using port 4369, which is not a privileged port...

Comment: I don't know why exactly, but it seems like my 4369 port, even if not listed in netstat, was used / blocked by something. Freeing this port solved this problem, so this is correct answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: I know I am late but try to kill antivirus, for me it was AVG blocking the port