# "could not load module E:\.....“,but the I have configured the enviroment variable ERLANG_HOME as D:...,

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I want to install RabbitMQ on windows 10. And I did as the offical mannual telling me that I have to install erlang first. I downloaded erlang and I configured the enviroment variable locating at D dish. And I open the cli, entered 'crl'. It said could not load module E:.....
E dish is not what I configured. So how to fix it?

Comment: There are other RabbitMQ communities where you can post your question: https://www.rabbitmq.com/contact.html#community-resources

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same problem because I was manually copying my Erlang directory around (due to missing admin rights). You might have [incorrect path entries](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/4CN4itJieHY/m/hYzQyrGuBwAJ) in your `PATH_TO_YOUR_ERLANG/bin/erl.ini` and `PATH_TO_YOUR_ERLANG/erts-X.Y.Z/bin/erl.ini` config files (`X.Y.Z` is the version of the Erlang runtime system, which depdends on the Erlang version you installed). Make sure that the config entries `Bindir` and `Rootdir` are referring to the correct path where you installed Erlang.

Side note: This also solved my follow-up problem of RabbitMQ not being able to start ([error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51629011/8176827) `Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: econnrefused`) because the Erlang Port Mapper Daemon `epmd` was not running (the `epmd.exe` is in the `PATH_TO_YOUR_ERLANG/erts-X.Y.Z/bin` directory, and if the paths in the config do not match, RabbitMQ cannot find it).